# Separate words by space and take into consideration that some contain apostrophe

Tags: javascript, regex

In my input field I have sometimes words that contain apostrophe or need to be searched using quotes.

Example of searched word: "de l'article".

I need to separate them by space, so I will have "de" and "l'article".

I tried:

```
let word = document.getElementById("searchedWord").value.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
let x = new RegExp("(" + word.replace(/\s+[']+/g, "|") + ")", "ig");
```

It doesn't seem to work properly. Can anyone help me write this regular expression?

Comment: what is `word`? Please supply a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Do you need to use a regex? I usually use `string.split` for this sort of thing as it's more human-legible

Comment: @Noam I added also the variable word for better understanding

Comment: Please add more examples that show that `Split` doesn't work for you.

Comment: Yeah the whole situation is still unclear, we need a working code. Not working as intended of course but working.

Comment: What is your problem? Replace each space with `|`? Just use `new RegExp("(" + word.replace(/\s+/g, "|") + ")", "g");`. Note you either do not need the parentheses or the `g` flag, it depends on your later code, please add it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out the split function :)

for example in order to split on every space

```
let x = "This is an example";
const myArray = x.split(' ');
let word = myArray[1]
```

word = 'This'

myArray = [This,is,an,example]